# Selecting and deselecting features with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to apply the algorithms "Random Points along Lines" at the feature level. I did some PyQGIS code to iterate through the features to select each individual instance and apply the algorithm in the layer with the selection, but it's not working properly.

In fact, the script works fine *until* I try include the `layer.removeSelection()` to clear the selection. It triggers an error below (in the run method though). If I don't include that line, the script works fine (but makes selection cumulative.)

I've tried few alternatives, but none seems to work. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

Code:

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

temp_layers = []

for f in layer.getFeatures():

    if f['remaining']:
        layer.removeSelection()
        layer.select(f.id())

        #layer.selectByIds([f.id()]) # alternative methods, same error

        print("selected: "+ str(layer.selectedFeatureCount()))
        print("selected: "+ str(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))
        print("new points: "+ str(f['remaining']))

        params = { 
            'INPUT' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True), 
            'MIN_DISTANCE' : 5, 
            'OUTPUT' : 'memory:', 
            'POINTS_NUMBER' : f['remaining'] 
        }

        results = processing.run('qgis:randompointsalongline', params)
        #results = processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:randompointsalongline', params)


# merging temp layers
params = {
    'LAYERS': temp_layers,
    'CRS': 'EPSG:3857',
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
}

processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:mergevectorlayers', params)
```

Comment: Would you accept another implementation method, for instance, one without PyQGIS?

Comment: Hi Leonardo Barleta, I'm using QGIS 3.4 and when I try and run the "Random Points along Lines" algorithm in QGIS with a tick in the selected features only checkbox the algorithm crashes - 'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RandomPointsAlongLines.py", line 130, in processAlgorithm
f = next(source.getFeatures(request.setFilterFid(fid).setSubsetOfAttributes([])))
StopIteration

Execution failed after 0.14 seconds' so perhaps it is a problem with the algorithm itself. Perhaps create a new layer from selection?

Comment: Remove`layer.removeSelection()` and try using `layer.selectByIds([f.id()], QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)`.